# Determine when a facebook friend shared post of specific type?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-fql

In my android app I want to know the time OR (Limit offset to get stream) when a specific friend shared a post of specific type say video. For example I want to know the time or (Limit offset of stream) when a user with id 522601313 last shared a video. I'll use it later in my FQL query like in

```
SELECT post_id, source_id, actor_id, target_id, message,
attachment, permalink, type , 
created_time,timeline_visibility,updated_time 
FROM stream WHERE source_id =522601313 and type=80 
limit = XXXX offset = XXXX
```

In above query I want to know limit and offset

Is it possible ?

If yes please suggest some solution how can I get this done?

Answer (score 0):

limit 1 to only retrieve lastest video upload, and get the created time too.

```
SELECT created_time, description, embed_html, format,length,link, owner, src, src_hq, thumbnail_link, title, updated_time, vid FROM video WHERE owner = 'USER_ID' LIMIT 1
```

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/video/

With the vid(let's say 803696294074), you can do more,

such as https://graph.facebook.com/803696294074?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

OR

https://graph.facebook.com/803696294074/comments?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

OR fql

```
SELECT text FROM comment where object_id=803696294074
```

Comment: I want to know  limit and offset which contains the video shared by a specific user